# Horizontal line (jpg) and other picture has a mysterious approx 5px distance. Newsletter HTML

Tags: html, css, email, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have troubles with making an HTML newsletter, but only at the part, where I have to insert a horizontal line without any spacing between the horizontal line and a picture.

I this at the moment (with and without borders):
[image]

And would like to achieve this:

[image]

I would like that white space to disappear. I've tried placing the  tag at the end of the line instead of placing it in a new line. Tried changing every borders, cellspacing, cellpadding, everything but nothing seems to work.

Here is the code for the HTML:

```
<!--email content-->
                    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="email-content" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!--section 1-->
                                <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img src="images/header1.jpg" width="600" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!--line break-->
                                <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="600" height="2" style="background-color: #178a01;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!--/line break-->
                                <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>   
                                            <h2 style="font-size: 26px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #178a01 !important; margin: 0px;">Nőnapi AKCIÓ! -50% páros kedvezmény</h2>
                                            <p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #292929; margin: 0px 15px;">Consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="#" style="color: #4b98d7; text-decoration: none;">Phasellus</a> a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit amet enim erat, in sagittis arcu. <a href="#" style="color: #292929; text-decoration: none;">Aliquam dolor dolor</a>, semper id tempor et, varius pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et.</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried padding and margin in css inline?

Comment: I did, but as far as I know outlook doesn't support it, or does it ?